# Only last element displays in sequence in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

If I click on the Next button chapter four displays and not chapter two or three and then four.

Can anybody help me? I haven't found a solution on internet and I tried for several days.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {

    $("p").html('2.This is chapter two<br /><br />');
    $("p").html('3.This is chapter three<br /><br />');
    $("p").html('4.This is chapter four<br /><br />');

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>

  <div class="book">
    <p>1.This is chapter one</p>

    <button>Next</button>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: You overwrite the `p` content. After click the button the `p` value is changed to `chapter2`, then on `chapter3` and then on `chapter4` in miliseconds, you can't see that. It's how your code works. You need to pass any variable, tell which one of contenets you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you keep overwriting `$("p").html()` each time you reference it. It does indeed change to `chapter 2`, but then changes to `chapter 3` and `chapter 4` so quickly that you don't notice it.

To get around this, what I recommend you do is to define a new variable to control the pages. On click of the button, increase this variable, and depending on what the variable is, update the `.html()` with the relevant content.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Set up a variable to control the pages
  var page = 1;
  
  $("button").click(function() {
  
    // Increase the page
    page++;
    
    // Show the relevant content
    if (page === 2) {
      $("p").html('2. This is chapter two<br />');
    }
    if (page === 3) {
      $("p").html('3. This is chapter three<br />');
    }
    if (page === 4) {
      $("p").html('4. This is chapter four<br />');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="book">
    <p>1. This is chapter one</p>
    <button>Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to store in variable what content you want to show.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // array of contents
    var contents = [
        '2.This is chapter two<br /><br />',
        '3.This is chapter three<br /><br />',
        '4.This is chapter four<br /><br />'
    ];

    $("button").click(function(){
       var p = $('p');
        var index = parseInt(p.data('value'));
          
        // write down a new content
        p.html(contents[index]);

        // increase an index for the next click
        p.data('value', index + 1)
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="book">
    <p data-value="0">1.This is chapter one</p> 
    <button>Next</button>
</div>
```